# Creating custom Linux for Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, gui

I want to know how I can do a custom Linux for Raspberry Pi.
I want to create something similar like Retropie (https://retropie.org.uk/). 
A Linux that boots my own front end GUI.

My plan would be:

Get a minimal Linux.
Let it boot and start graphic processes needed to display opengl stuff then launch my front end gui (I want to do that in SDL or so) and my front end communicates then with all system processes e.g. enter wlan password or set display resolution ... .

I don't know how to do that (linux boot and launch my gui), maybe someone has some experience or guidance for me :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

What you are saying is that you are wanting to create you own Desktop Environment, like LXDE, XFCE, Gnome or KDE. Start by reading [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646273/custom-linux-gui-where-to-begin). I recommend you stick with a headless Raspbian for your "minimal Linux," as Raspbian will maintain the drivers you need for not only the current Raspberry Pi's, but future ones as well. Just remember, Raspberry Pi's use some drivers that are NOT open-source, therefore when a new Raspberry Pi comes out, if you are not on Raspbian or one of it's derivatives, you will not be able to run on the new devices.

Comment: A [desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) is a more specific kind of thing than a "GUI frontend"; an ATM bank machine has a GUI frontend but it is not a DE.  The defining characteristics of a DE would be it provides 1) A window manager (WM), which may be independent, 2) An integrated file manager, and probably a few other apps like a terminal emulator, and 3) Some kind of taskbar and menu interface.   I am guessing Retropie does not provide a DE because it does not need to.

Comment: The question you link to does seem focussed on creating a full-blown DE but the OP here seems interested in something somewhat simpler that could be done just with SDL (I doubt very much anyone does a DE that way, but many "GUI front ends" would be).  So s/he could start off with a GUI-less distro/variant (such as jessie-lite) but will have to add the Xorg server, etc.  Although SDL once supported a framebuffer mode that could run without X, I think this is no longer the case (but I could be wrong about that).

Comment: Although it's not very relevant here, note also the distinction between a DE and a [WM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager).  The former requires the latter but the reverse is not true and you can run a reasonably functional desktop with just a WM, depending on the WM (e.g., my preference when I use a GUI on the pi is stand-alone FVWM).   The three fundamental layers of most desktops on linux are 1) The Xorg server, 2) The window manager, 3) The desktop environment.  The higher numbered layers depend on the lower ones.